# How to call more than one function with same name but different properties? Adding data & setup to SpreadsheetView pod file

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, spreadsheet

I am trying to setup the column and row headers in the pod file SpreadsheetView. I'm attempting to setup the column headers and row headers with my title arrays and I've successfully gotten the column headers setup. However now I can't re-call the same function to do the same thing with row headers.

This func sets them up but it of course can't be called twice:
Buuuut since I'm a noob and will try anything random, I renamed the function to spreadsheetViewII but that doesn't fly. Is my array not linking with the code or something else wrong? Again back to the original question...

```
func spreadsheetViewII(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyLabelCell
    cell.setup(with: "Cell")
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.setup(with: rowHeaders[indexPath.row])
    }
    return cell
}
```

This is my basic noob question and confusion.
How do I setup both headers AND also later add values to the sheet?

```
import UIKit
import SpreadsheetView

class MetricVerticalViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, SpreadsheetViewDataSource, SpreadsheetViewDelegate {

private let spreadsheetView = SpreadsheetView()
@IBOutlet weak var brickHeight: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    spreadsheetView.register(MyLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier)
    spreadsheetView.delegate = self
    spreadsheetView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(spreadsheetView)
    rowTitles()
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// Sets spreadsheets initial position
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    spreadsheetView.frame = CGRect(x: 18, y: 235, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height-100)
}

// Column and row headers
let columnHeaders: [String] = ["", "6mm", "7mm", "8mm", "9mm", "10mm", "11mm", "12mm", "13nn", "14mm"]
var rowHeaders: [String] = []
func rowTitles() {
    for index in 1...100 {
        let rows = ("Row: \(index)")
        rowHeaders.append(rows)
    }
}

// Something to do with inserting data to the sheet
func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
    let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyLabelCell
    cell.setup(with: "Cell")
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.setup(with: columnHeaders[indexPath.section])
    }
    return cell
}

func spreadsheetViewII(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
    let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyLabelCell
        cell.setup(with: "Cell")
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.setup(with: rowHeaders[indexPath.row])
        }
        return cell
    }

// Spreadsheet setup
func numberOfColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    columnHeaders.count }
func numberOfRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    rowHeaders.count }
func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, widthForColumn column: Int) -> CGFloat {
    70  }
func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, heightForRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    18  }
func frozenColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    1   }
func frozenRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    1   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled this with a switch if statement inside the function.

```
    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
    let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyLabelCell
    cell.setup(with: "Cell")
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    if case 0 = indexPath.row {
        cell.setup(with: columnHeaders[indexPath.section])
        return cell
    } else if case 0 = indexPath.section {
        cell.setup(with: rowHeaders[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    return cell
}
```